# React component prop throwing error typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I'm trying to use a component on which I have defined the prop type like this

```
export type Props = {
  variant: "green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow";
};
```

and the component is like this

```
const Tag: FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { variant, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <div
      {...rest}
      sx={{
        bg: variant,
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Now when I try to consume this component like this

```
const statusColour: { [key: string]: string } = {
  running: "green",
  stopped: "red",
  idle: "grey",
  default: "green"
};

const variant = statusColour[value]
          ? statusColour[value]
          : statusColour["default"];

<Tag variant={variant} />
```

I get this error on the `variant` attribute

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow"'.ts(2322)

> types.d.ts(2, 5): The expected type comes from property 'variant' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & TagProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'

> (JSX attribute) variant: "green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow"

Can somebody help me out on how to resolve it, thanks

Comment: what is `Props` in second code? Is it from the first code?

Comment: In the second one, it's an array of object and some other data. Basically when I loop over the array, there I get the status which is later then used to render the `Tag` component

Comment: In terms of type, because I guess `react` also provides a `Props` type and u have also created it. So, is this your `Props` type or `react's`

Comment: sorry, which props are you talking about? The Tag one or the other component.

Comment: `FC<Props>` <- this

Answer (score 1):

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow"'.ts(2322)

This error means that any string of type `string` is not assignable to the union of *specific* strings `"green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow"`. This makes sense. `"banana"` is a `string`, but it should NOT be assignable to `"apple" | "pear"`.

To fix it you need to tell the type of `statusColor` that it may only have values that are one of those specific strings.

So just make the values of your mapped type the same as the `variant` in `Props`.

```
const statusColour: { [key: string]: Props['variant'] } = {
  running: "green",
  stopped: "red",
  idle: "grey",
  default: "green"
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2&ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDNIAekscMAnmEjgAFKmADOcALy5mcOADcUUYCgB2MAFxwARAHMGSVdrgAfHQwAmxs3oa9rO3kgA2ziAHdtAbmYkfzNAhVMXgAFRRdLSIAHhEIcQA+KTgACjBRMQBKKSScWThA4Pg8RWU1LDgAOmqGENJk9PixHzkGGABXKFU4aITogHoE339CupCUDrFCCDdOrTwAbQBrJF4tEOVVXQBdLTjxBdpSlXVabfrpPNb21VVgLa1bJENtTHyQ+IELR8tX-OALM4kI99Ks-nILEhyCh2s5NDpQS9hqxRvBjuVkuNJtNZlBKlAbnctiignUYEg6tJouFdAolCcYJIcOj1GRBkA)

---

Or clean it up by making the variant union it's own type alias:

```
type MyVariant = "green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow"

export type Props = {
  variant: MyVariant;
};

const statusColour: { [key: string]: MyVariant } = {
  running: "green",
  stopped: "red",
  idle: "grey",
  default: "green"
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQFDMwCeYScAsuwGooowFADt4AXjgAiAOYMko6XAA+MhgBNlauQ3baZ7JABtjEAO7TWSAB6RYcDlzgAFKmADOcKTmZw4AG5CIuIAXLwCwWIwANzMJHHMaBCiHvAAKiiy4UQAPG4QngB83nAAFGDuHgCU3iW+-smp8HhBwtHYAHTdDGmkpZWFHnH+DDAArlCicLlFuQD0RfGJTX1pKBMehBBmk+F4ANoA1kjs4WnCorIAuuF8gu3i-T5+cFDjoqLAV+G6SIrSTCvNKFLgaX6aQGvYAaYxIX7yU5Q-waJDkFDjYwwBEKJTLVireBtEKSODrTbbXZQTrvT7fWQElJ9GBIPpSXKZWSBKLiCQ4YnRMiLIA)

Answer (score 0):

so figured out my mistake. Basically, the `variant` prop expected something of type `"green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow";` but I was passing a string. To resolve it, this is what I did:

```
const statusColour: { [key: string]: string } = {
  running: "green",
  stopped: "red",
  idle: "grey",
  default: "green"
};

const variant = statusColour[value] as "green" | "red" | "grey" | "yellow"
          

<Tag variant={variant} />
```

I know this is not the best solution. So if somebody could post a better solution, that would be super helpful. Thanks

Comment: This is not a good solution. This casts `string` to a more specific type unsafely. Using `as` tells the compiler that you know better than it does. You're better off using _stricter_ types so that you don't have to cast the value at all.

Comment: @AlexWayne I get your point. But here I need to do this because the `statusColour` is being used at some other places too. If I impose a stricter type, the other parts would break.

the only way I can get the stricter type is by creating a separate object for variant and that. seems sort of an over engineering to me when I know what would go over here. But if you have some other suggestions, I'm all ears. :)